# Import @aspnet/signalr in Vue application

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to import SignalR in my Vue.JS application. I use webpack to bundle modules.

In my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.0"
}
```

In my component within script section:

```
<script>
  import  signalR  from '@aspnet/signalr';**
  ...
</script>
```

I can see signalR references in **main.js** (generated by webpack), but when I try to access it the mounted lifehook, I get the error in console:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'signalR') was not found in
>   '@aspnet/signalr'

How to import SignalR in a Vue component correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to import it this way:

```
const signalR = require('@aspnet/signalr');
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. The reason it doesn't work via import is that there is no 'export default' in signalr module itself?

Comment: Yes, it is older library, not supporting ES6 modules.

Answer (score 7):

Try to import it this way:

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
```